# I cant import scipy.spacial.distance properly

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-spatial, boids

```
from scipy.spacial.distance import squareform, pdist, cdist
```

it says 'could not be resolved'. I am using python for a boids program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found out that `scipy.spatial.distance` is the correct spelling of the Module. Did you try import that?

Comment: oh god that was a stupid mistake. thanks mate